# Why do Flutter Widgets like Column() not require `.children`

Tags: flutter

It seems really off that you can return `Column()` without any error from the compiler. What is a column without children?

Internally, it defaults `children: const []`.

Does anyone know what the rationale is here? It seems like it's blocking the compiler from pointing out some pretty obvious errors and will also swallow null values that you didn't intend to be null.

Comment: An empty list is not a null value.

Comment: I understand that, I'm just curious why it would not require that some children be specified

Answer (score 0):

A column has a default size in the Flutter code, which is 0. If a widget is added, the size changes so that the widget fits in. Furthermore, children: [] is only a list, and if it is empty, no widget will be displayed. ¯_(ツ)_/¯

This is btw. the Column class:

```
class Column extends Flex {
  /// Creates a vertical array of children.
  ///
  /// The [mainAxisAlignment], [mainAxisSize], [crossAxisAlignment], and
  /// [verticalDirection] arguments must not be null.
  /// If [crossAxisAlignment] is [CrossAxisAlignment.baseline], then
  /// [textBaseline] must not be null.
  ///
  /// The [textDirection] argument defaults to the ambient [Directionality], if
  /// any. If there is no ambient directionality, and a text direction is going
  /// to be necessary to disambiguate `start` or `end` values for the
  /// [crossAxisAlignment], the [textDirection] must not be null.
  Column({
    Key? key,
    MainAxisAlignment mainAxisAlignment = MainAxisAlignment.start,
    MainAxisSize mainAxisSize = MainAxisSize.max,
    CrossAxisAlignment crossAxisAlignment = CrossAxisAlignment.center,
    TextDirection? textDirection,
    VerticalDirection verticalDirection = VerticalDirection.down,
    TextBaseline? textBaseline,
    List<Widget> children = const <Widget>[],
  }) : super(
    children: children,
    key: key,
    direction: Axis.vertical,
    mainAxisAlignment: mainAxisAlignment,
    mainAxisSize: mainAxisSize,
    crossAxisAlignment: crossAxisAlignment,
    textDirection: textDirection,
    verticalDirection: verticalDirection,
    textBaseline: textBaseline,
  );
}
```

Comment: Right, it just seems less useful this way. A column without children is most likely a mistake by the developer, requiring an explicit [] seems to me much more helpful.

I was mainly just curious if there was a history on this, or rational that explains it from the Flutter Teams perspective, as it seems counter-productive.